# parametrize triangles meeting certain conditions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Consider triangles with angles alpha, beta, gamma  such that gamma = 2 alpha, and sides (a,b,c) are integers.  I want to parametrize such triangles by a single integer or rational variable.

Comment: Have you tried to use the law of cosines?

Comment: There are two degrees of freedom here. Not possible to use only a single variable to parametrize the triangles.

Comment: I meant,  up to similarity.

Comment: I guessed as much. Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Konstantine Zelator, [Integral Triangles](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0497) with one angle twice another, and with the bisector(of the double angle) also of integral length. The abstract says, "In Result 2 in Section 5, we offer 3-parameter formulas that describe the entire family of integral triangles $ABC$ with $\angle A=2\angle B$." But it seems it's actually Result 1.

Result 1: The entire family of integral triangles $ABC$, with angle at $B$ being twice the angle at $A$; can be parametrically described (in terms of three integer parameters) as follows:

Sidelengths $a=\ell k^2$, $b=\ell km$, $c=\ell(m^2-k^2)$; where $\ell,m,k$
are positive integers such that $k$ and $m$
are relatively prime and with either, $k^2 < m^2 < 2k^2$ or alternatively, $2k^2 < m^2 < 4k^2$.

Comment: See also R. S. Luthar, Integer-sided triangles with one angle twice another, College Mathematics Journal, January, 1984, available at https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0746834215798.di020710.02p0187t.pdf  The question was also given as a coding challenge in 2015: https://www.codewars.com/kata/integer-triangles-having-one-angle-the-double-of-another-one

Comment: The question asks for a **single** variable parametrization.

Comment: k/m can be regarded as the single rational parameter I asked for.